# View all member articles on Firebase! Javascript webapp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a site where I want to add articles through Firebase, and I came up with the following code that displays the summary of articles, but it is some articles created by the user, and I want to modify it to display all articles created by other users

```
function allIndex(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        user ? firebase.database().ref(user.displayName).child("Posts").orderByChild("updatedAt").on("value", function(user) {
            var t = "";
            user.forEach(function(user) {
                entry = user.val(), t = '<div class="article"><a href="my-posts.html?id=' + user.getKey() + '"><div class="panel-heading">' + excerpt(entry.title, 140) + '</div><div class="panel-body"><small>' + datetimeFormat(entry.updatedAt) + '</small></div></a><small class="' + entry.status + '">' + entry.status + "</small></div>" + t
            }), $("#entries.post").removeClass("loading").find(".loader").remove(), $("#entries.post .panel_content").append(t)
        }) : (alert("Please login first"), window.location.href = "sign-in.html")
    })
}
```

---

This is some associated logic which justifies the structure

```
function create() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(n) {
        n ? (tinymce.init({
          
        }), $("#new_entry").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), (e = {}).title = $(this).find('[name="title"]').val(), e.description = $(this).find('[name="description"]').val(), e.labels = $(this).find('[name="labels"]').val(), e.content = tinymce.get("content").getContent(), e.createdAt = (new Date).getTime(), e.updatedAt = e.createdAt, e.views = 0, e.status = "Pending";
               var t = firebase.database().ref(n.displayName),
                a = t.child("Posts");
            return t.child("Points").transaction(function(e) {
                return (e || 0) + 10
            }), a.push(e).then(function(e) {
                window.location.href = "my-posts.html?id=" + e.getKey()
            }).catch(function(e) {
                alert(e), console.error(e)
            }), !1
        })) : (alert("Please login first"), window.location.href = "sign-in.html")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a structure like this:

```
$userName: {
  Posts: {
    "post1": { ... },
    "post2": { ... },
    ...
  }
}
```

Right now you're loading the posts from a specific user, and adding them to the HTML. To load the posts of all users, you'll need to:

1. Load the data from one level higher in your database.
2. Then loop over each user in your callback.

```
firebase.database().ref().on("value", function(users) {
  var t = "";
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    user.val().Posts.forEach(function(post) {
      ... handle post here
    })
  })
})
```

---

You'll note that we no longer order on `updatedAt`, as that is not possible in your current data structure across all users. If you want to show all posts for all users by `updatedAt`, consider changing your data structure to a flat list of posts, with the user name being a property in each:

```
Posts: {
  "post1": { username: "...", ... },
  "post2": { username: "...", ... },
  ...
}
```